# С помощью какой формулы можно проверить вхождение точки в область?

Tags: c#, математика

Как можно проверить вхождение точки в зеленую област?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какую формулу можно видоизменить под это или какую использовать?

Comment: Попадает внутрь большой окружности, но при этом не попадает ни в одну из 2-х маленьких.

Comment: @avp Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать?

Comment: конкретной формулы для этого кейса я не знаю, но есть уравнение окружности `(x – a)^2 + (y – b)^2 <= R^2` им можно проверит попадает или нет, просто применить её 3 раза, для большой оно должно попадать, а для двух маленьких нет

Comment: Малые окружности симметричны относительно оси ординат, так что достаточно одной формулы для проверки попадания в любую из них.

Comment: Дистанция между точками `Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x2-x1,2)+Math.Pow(y2-y1,2));`

Answer (score 1):

Если считать, что один квадратик имеет сторону 1, так что радиус большой окружности - 2, малых - 1, то для зеленых точек должны выполняться все три условия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знаки "меньше/больше" или "меньше или равно/больше или равно" выберите сами в зависимости от того, как быть с точками на окружностях, куда они входят.